# C++ prints "once *some number* is *another number* " multiple times while I don't print anything in the code (I need an answer in next half an hour)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I try to fill two-dimensional array with random values:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        int temp = rand();
        *(array + i * size + j) = &temp;
    }
}
```

The size variable is set earlier in the code. Array initialization:

```
int** array = new int * [5];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    array[i] = new int[5];
```

I don't do anything other than that later in code. Pls help.

Comment: This is not a [mcve].  The code provided does not compile.  It is missing header files, and function bodies, and main.  (I did not downvote.)

Comment: `*(array + i * size + j)` That's the same as `array[i * size + j]` which makes it more obvious it's wrong. `= &temp;` Don't add random `&`'s just to make arbitrary code compile.

Comment: We understood your problem by looking at the code, but the title is unclear and you're asking nothing in your question. Try to be clearer next time ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahah, pointers :D

### For arrays, you can use the `[]` operator to access an element by it's index.

That would change your:

```
int temp = rand();
*(array + i * size + j) = &temp;
```

into (note that the two have the exact same effect):

```
int temp = rand();
array[i * size + j] = &temp;
```

Which is way cleaner! But also false. Right now, you are accessing an element of a two dimentionnal array, that is, an array. And assigning an pointer to int to an array is probably giving you an error.

I understand your thought process, but `i * size + j` is used when you want to fake two dimentions in a single one, no need here ^^. You need to access the element at i,j and assign it temp directly, as with a normal int. Then how to access this element? This way:

```
int temp = rand();
array[i][j] = temp;
```

If for some reason you wish to keep your pointers, you can also access it this way:

```
int temp = rand();
*(*(array + i) + j) = temp;
```